# I am trying to add dynamic rows in jquery but i am getting syntax error in for loop

Tags: jquery

```js
var scale = data.sizeWiseList;
var len = scale.length;

    '<table class="table table-bordered">'+
               '<tr>'+
               for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                   var size = scale[i].sizeDesc;
                   
               
                
                '<th>'+size+
                
                
                '</th>'+
               }
```

Comment: You can't concatenate a `for` loop into a string

Comment: @Phil agree with you. There is moreeee that needs to be done with part of code above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
var scale = data.sizeWiseList;
var table = $("<table>", {
  class: "table table-bordered"
}).appendTo("body");
$("<tr>").appendTo(table);
$.each(scale, function(i, s){
  $("<th>").html(s.sizeDesc).appendTo($("tr:last", table));
}
```

Your post does not define `data`, so I cannot test or confirm if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const html = "";

for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                   var size = scale[i].sizeDesc;
                   
               
                
                html += '<th>'+size+ '</th>';
               }

 html = '<table class="table table-bordered">'+ '<tr>'+ html;

document.write(html);
```

- javascript is not a template language with which inline string dumping renders things onto the page.
- for loop does not return a value nor can be used as a sub clause of an expression.
- When you use `+`, your intention seems to be to stream the string parts onto the screen. I wish it could work that way too. But no, in JavaScript, it only means to concatenate strings, and you need to have a variable to carry the result.
- Your code does not use JQuery, neither does mine.